# nested OR query is not working in nest js project with mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nestjs, prisma

Schema in Prisma file

here described the relation between booking model, webUser and appUser

```
model Booking {
  id                       String                     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  venueId                  String?                    @db.ObjectId // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above
  phone                    String
  eventId                  String?                    @db.ObjectId
  webUser                  webUser[]                  @relation(fields: [webUserId], references: [id])
  webUserId                String[]                    @db.ObjectId
}

model webUser {
id                       String                     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
phone                    String
name                     String?
email                    String?
booking                  Booking[]
}
```

and this is the query I'm performing to implement search functionality

```
if(search){
 bookingWhereQuery = {
        webUser :{
          some :{
            OR: [
              { email: { contains:search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
              { name: { contains:search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
              { phone: { contains:search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
            ],  
          }
        }
      };
}

const testingData = await this.prisma.booking.findMany({
      where:{
      ...bookingWhereQuery,
      eventId:eventId,
      venueId:venueId,
      },
     include: {
       webUser: true,
      },
    })
```

so when I run this code I'm getting empty testingData array even though there is a data which fulfilled this conditions

can anyone tell what is wrong and where or any other way to implement this same logic without changing the meaning